# Disable MS Edge JSON Viewer via Selenium EdgeOptions

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

A recent Edge update has caused a large number of our Selenium-powered integration tests to fail due to the JSON Viewer, which apparently is now enabled by default. It no longer renders the file content in a simple `<pre>` but adds a ton of nested `<div>`s.

Disabling the JSON Viewer would restore functionality, and I suppose it may be possible to do so via the `EdgeOptions`. However, I have not been able to find out how the option for the JSON Viewer is called.

My config:

```java
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();

Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
prefs.put("download.default_directory", TMP_DIRECTORY.toString());
prefs.put("download.directory_upgrade", true);
// prefs.put(<enable json viewer>, false); <-- what I would like to add

options
    .setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs)
    ...
```

---

**EDIT**: Solved per [Xudong Peng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15690271/xudong-peng)'s reply as follows:

```java
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();

Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
prefs.put("download.default_directory", TMP_DIRECTORY.toString());
prefs.put("download.directory_upgrade", true);

List<String> arguments = new ArrayList<>();
arguments.add("--disable-features=msEdgeJSONViewer");

options
    .setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs)
    .addArguments(arguments)
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable the JSON Viewer in Microsoft Edge with Selenium, just add argument in `EdgeOptions`, something like this:

```
options.AddArgument("--disable-features=msEdgeJSONViewer");
```

You can check if that work in `edge://version`:
[image]